# AWS Route 53. Routing from naked URL to WWW

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I've got an application running on Elastic Beanstalk. The DNS is handled by Route 53 and the Certificate for HTTPS is handled by AWS Certificate manager.

The certificate is for the domain *.example.com

I have a CNAME in Route 53 for www.example.com pointing to the EBS application URL.

However I'm struggling get a way to access the site with just example.com.

I've set an Alias for example.com pointing towards the application but I get an error in the browser that the connection is insecure because the certificate is for *.example.com and I assume doesn't cover example.com.

Is there some way I can get around this? Some way I can just do a straight redirect from the naked URL to the www. url?

Thanks

Comment: AWS Certificate manager should allow you to add both `example.com` and `*.example.com` to the same certificate.

Comment: @DusanBajic has it right. Docs are here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-request.html. "To add more domain names to the ACM Certificate, choose Add more names and type another domain name in the text box that opens. This is useful for protecting both a bare or apex domain (like example.com) and its subdomains (*.example.com)."